# While compiling AHB_Generate.pl script, this is the error I am getting

Tags: perl, perl-module

> Can't locate Tk.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.5/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.5 /usr/lib64/perl5/site_perl/5.8.5/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib64/perl5/site_perl/5.8.4/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib64/perl5/site_perl/5.8.3/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib64/perl5/site_perl/5.8.2/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib64/perl5/site_perl/5.8.1/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib64/perl5/site_perl/5.8.0/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.5 /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.4 /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.3 /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.2 /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.1 /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.0 /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.5/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.4/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.3/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_Perl/5.8.2/x86_64-Linux-thread-multi /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.1/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.0/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.5 /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.4 /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.3 /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.2 /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.1 /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.0 /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl .) at AHB_Generate.pl line 3.

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

If you do not have the Tk module installed, this would be a good reason. One suggestion I have is to `sudo cpanp install Tk`.